# ESlint throw errors instead of warnings

Tags: javascript, eslint, create-react-app

Is it possible to throw errors instead of warnings using Eslint?
I am working with a `create-react-app` and want to have a really strict lint policy in my team, and thought that this might be a good start.

Is that possible?

Comment: You have to configure the rule to be as strict as you want them: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuring-rules

Answer (score 69, accepted):

`--max-warnings` can serve this purpose: `--max-warnings=0` means that any warnings cause eslint to report an error.

https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/2309#issuecomment-219828044

Answer (score -5):

Yes It is possible to edit the ESlint Configuration in create-react-app setup. All you need to do is run `npm run eject` in your project setup. This will allow you to edit the default project configurations according to your needs.

After ejecting you will find a `eslintConfig` key in your project root's `package.json` file. Just delete this option from the package.json. You can add your own custom configuration for the Eslint by adding a `.eslintrc` file in your project root directory. You can read about different rules and configurations [here](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuring-rules)