# How do I set an Angular project to always emit errors instead of warnings when linting?

Tags: angular, eslint

Entire question is in the title :) . I've looked around a bit and found that there is an `emitError` setting that exists for ESLint, but it looks like it's tucked away inside the Webpack configuration for `eslint-loader`, which Angular does not appear to expose.

Am I missing something? Or is this option inaccessable? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by changing the script you use to trigger linting according to [ESlint throw errors instead of warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51346302/eslint-throw-errors-instead-of-warnings)

example eslintrc.js

```js
module.exports = {
    parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
    parserOptions: {
      project: 'tsconfig.json',
      tsconfigRootDir : __dirname,
      sourceType: 'module',
    },
    plugins: ['@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin'],
    extends: [
      'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
      'plugin:prettier/recommended',
    ],
    root: true,
    env: {
      node: true,
      jest: true,
    },
    ignorePatterns: ['.eslintrc.js'],
    rules: {
      '@typescript-eslint/interface-name-prefix': 'off',
      '@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type': 'off',
      '@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types': 'off',
      '@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any': 'off',
    },
  };
```

example package.json

```json
{
  ...

  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --max-warnings=0"
  },
  
  ...
}
```

the important part here is the "lint" command, which calls eslint to lint src, apps, libs, and test with 0 warnings. This means all warnings will be regarded as errors